# create-react-app how to compile specific .ts file to .js file in the build process?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app, react-scripts

Currently, `$ npm run build` compiles files from `src/` into `/build` and everything is working fine. However, there's some specific TypeScript file, `src/integer.ts`, that I want to compile to its own JavaScript file, `build/integer.js` and all the other files to be compiled "normally".

This is the project structure:

```
/src
/build
```

Here's the `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
}
...
"scripts": {
     "build": "react-scripts build",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question. Both the esnext javascript and typescript will be compiled to es5. What special compilation do you need?

Comment: Not a very good answer. There are many reasons one would want to do that.